# PDO could not be converted to string php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Learning PHP OOP way:

Pass database class object to other class i got this message ' Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string  ' , meanwhile  the code work fine if I comment this line '`//$imageobj= new image($dbobj);`' ?

**Update** : once I add this line `$this->dbconn=null;` to `getConnection()` function in db.class.php before try{} . every thing WORKS fine !!!

> index.php

```
<?php
include "./classes/db.class.php";
include "./classes/image.class.php";

$dbobj= new db();
$imageobj= new image($dbobj);

$page_title="Shopping Center !";
include './template/header.php';

$dbobj->getConnection();

include './template/footer.php';
```

> db.class.php

```
class db {
    private $host;
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbconn;
    private $status;

    public function __construct() {
        // the require paramaters to start db connnection
        $this->host = '127.0.0.1';
        $this->dbname = 'shop_carta';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->status = 0;
        //$this->dbconn = null;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        try {
            $this->dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbconn", $this->username, $this->password);
            if (!is_null($this->dbconn)) {

                $this->status = $this->dbconn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);
                $this->dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $this->dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                return $this->dbconn;
            } else {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"
                . " Our server Busy Now try again later.. </div></br>";
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
              return false;
        }}}
```

> image.class.php
>   this class receive the $dbobject try to $dbobject->getConncetion() and set retrieve

```
class image {
    private $table_name = 'product_images';
    private $dbconn;
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($dbobj) {
         $this->dbconn = $dbobj->getConnection();
       }}
```

[image: Error message once you pass $dbobj to image class]

[image: once you commit line $imageobj= new image($dbobj); in index.php]

**Assign dbconn to null solve :** 
**Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string.
Any suggestion WHY ?** 
[image]

Comment: show the code of the image class - seems the constructor of `image` does only accept strings, but you are passing a whole `db` object

Comment: class image {
    private $table_name = 'product_images';
    private $dbconn;
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($dbobj) {
         $this->dbconn = $dbobj->getConnection();
       }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies here:

```
"mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbconn"
```

dbname should be a database name. You are providing a property, which (before you added $this->dbconn = null) does not exist, which is why you get an error.

Adding $this->dbconn = null, does prevents the fatal on the non existant property, but youre still providing an empty database name.

You should fix it by replacing it with $this->dbname, like so:

```
"mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname"
```

Comment: That was stupid mistake  feels so dumb :/ . Thanks @Erik .